# Descomprimir archivo RAR con contraseña usando SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#

Quiero descomprimir un archivo con extensión `rar` usando [`SevenZipSharp`](https://github.com/luuksommers/SevenZipSharp.Interop/) en C#, pero siempre me arroja la siguiente excepción, aunque la contraseña sea la correcta:

> SevenZip.SevenZipArchiveException: Invalid archive: open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong password was provided?
>   If your archive is an exotic one, it is possible that SevenZipSharp has no signature for its format and thus decided it is TAR by mistake.

**Nota:** Estoy seguro que la contraseña es la correcta por que ya descomprimí el archivo (manualmente) usando `7zip` desde el explorador de Windows.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
try
{
    using (SevenZipExtractor extr = new SevenZipExtractor(zipPath, ZipPassword))
    {
        //el formato es Rar, asi que si esta detectando el tipo de archivo
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(extr.Format);
        //si esta recibiendo la contrasenia que yo le estoy enviando
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(extr.Password);
        success = extr.ArchiveFileNames.Count > 0;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Este método solo esta comprobando si la contraseña es correcta, para en caso necesario volver a solicitarla al usuario.

Comment: Ese paquete depende de un proyecto que ya no tiene soporte. Deberías usar este nuget, que es un fork de ese proyecto original: https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp

Comment: pues sigo con el mismo error, `extr.Check()` no arroja error, pero `extr.ExtractArchive(outputFolder);` sigue arrojando el mismo error